# Reference for compact ordered spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, order-theory

A compact ordered topological spaces is a compact topological space $(X, \tau)$ together with a partial ordered $\leq$ on $X$ such that $\leq \subseteq X^2$ is a closed subset in the product topology.

I am wondering if the standard references for the information about these kind of spaces (or ordered topological spaces in general) is still Nachbin's *Order and topology* (1965) or if there exists more recent surveys on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following references might be of interest:

M. Erné, [The ABC of order and topology](http://www.heldermann.de/R&E/RAE18/ctw05.pdf)
(1991)

Morgan Kamga's thesis, [Topology and order](https://library.nexteinstein.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/morgan2004-5.pdf) (2005)